# Unable to truncate table in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, truncate

I am trying to truncate a table in my Postgres DB using a python script:

```
conn = get_psql_conn()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""TRUNCATE table table_name;""")

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Nothing happens.
The script finishes quickly, no error is raised.
The table still has its rows.
I was able to execute other queries with no problem using the same setup.

I did appreciate it if anyone can point out my mistake here!
Thanks

Comment: Hey @smiffy I would probably check the permission of the user associated with that connection. You might be missing some required permissions to truncate the table.

Comment: is it normal to have so many double quotes ?

Comment: Just a guess, as we don't see how the postgres connection is made. You probably need to commit after executing a SQL statement: `con.commit()`

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed con.commit() solved it, i didnt know it was needed here as all other queries worked without. However in those i was only reading from the db which seems to make the diffrence ;) Maybe permission was needed aswell, i added them before adding con.commit()

Comment: No it was the commit(). Your other queries where probably `SELECT(s)` that did not change anything.

Comment: how to know weather this truncate statement is executed successfully here?